# Django Forms with multiple models

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to have a several part form that includes property(address) upload date, inspector, and inspectee. There is an add area button that adds a name of an area(backyard,etc) and notes to go along with that area. lastly there is a picture that lets you upload a picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB9Na.png)

When i add an area that seems to be working to me. it adds the inputs. the problem is when i click upload i get these errors. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztcAV.png). The problem is that I have seperate models for the property, inspection, areas, and area images. The idea is that one property should have an inspection, many areas, and each area could have one or more images. Im sure the view is wrong, but I don't know what to do. Maybe its because the inspection form hasnt been submitted so lines in the views like this dont work

```
area.property = inspection.property  # Set the property field
```

Although im not sure why i wouldnt get a serverside error when submitting then

Here are my models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Add any additional fields here
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Property(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='properties')
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='property_images/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name='areas', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} in {self.property.address}"

class AreaImage(models.Model):
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Image for {self.area.name} in {self.area.property.address}"
    

class Inspection(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    inspector = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='inspections_conducted')
    inspected_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='inspections_received')
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Inspection for {self.property.address} on {self.date}"
```

Here is the view

```
@user_passes_test(is_inspector)
def upload_inspection(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        inspection_form = InspectionForm(request.POST)
        if inspection_form.is_valid():
            inspection = inspection_form.save()
            for area_data in request.POST.getlist('areas'):
                area_form = AreaForm(area_data)
                if area_form.is_valid():
                    area = area_form.save(commit=False)
                    area.inspection = inspection
                    area.property = inspection.property  # Set the property field
                    area.save()
                    for image_data in area_data.getlist('images'):
                        image_form = AreaImageForm(image_data, request.FILES)
                        if image_form.is_valid():
                            image = image_form.save(commit=False)
                            image.area = area  # Set the area field
                            image.save()
            return redirect('user_home')
    else:
        inspection_form = InspectionForm()
        area_form = AreaForm()
        area_image_form = AreaImageForm()
    return render(request, 'propertyrental/uploadinspection.html', {
        'inspection_form': inspection_form,
        'area_form': area_form,
        'area_image_form': area_image_form
    })
```

here is the html and js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Document is ready");
    var areaIndex = 1;
    $("#add_area").click(function(){
        console.log("Add Area button clicked");
        var area_form = $(".area_form:first").clone(true); // Clone the form, including event handlers
        console.log("Form cloned", area_form);
        area_form.find('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
            var newName = $(this).attr('name').replace('0', areaIndex);
            $(this).attr('name', newName);
            $(this).val(''); // Clear the input value
        });
        area_form.show(); // Show the form
        $("#areas").append(area_form);
        console.log("Form appended", area_form);
        areaIndex++;
    });
});



{% extends "propertyrental/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'propertyrental/js/scripts.js' %}"></script>





<h1 class = "help text-center">You can upload your inspection here!</h1>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ inspection_form.as_p }}
    <div id="areas">
        <div class="area_form" style="display: none;">
            {{ area_form.as_p }}
            {{ area_image_form.as_p }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="add_area">Add Area</button>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>



{% endblock %}
```